# MVC json save file

Tags: json, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013

I got a view with some textbox and a submit button
when i push submit i want the data of the textboxes in a json file(no database)

Now it works only for save 1data command when i psuh a second time on submit with other data
then hen rewrite my json file how can i save all of it ?

Controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //   jsonkalender.Add(new kalender() { Password = "" });
            //kalender kl = new kalender();
            //kl.Password = obj.Password;
            //kl.MyEnum = TestEnum.taak;
            //obj.Password = kl.Password;
            //Load(null);
            return View();
        }
        private const string JsonFileName1 = @"C:\\Users\Alexander\Desktop\times1.json";
        private List<kalender> _times;

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(kalender obj)
        {
          //  Load(obj);
          //  _times.Add(new kalender() { Datum = DateTime.Now.ToString() });
            kalender kl = new kalender();
           Json(new { datum = obj.Datum,wachtwoord = obj.Password });
           // _times.Add(obj);

            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception) { }

            obj.SelectedEnumId++;

          //  kl.Password = obj.Password;
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);


            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(JsonFileName1))
            {
                writer.Write(json);

            }
            return View();
        }    

        private void Load(kalender obj)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(JsonFileName1))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(JsonFileName1))
                {
                    var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<kalender>(json);
                }
            }

            if (obj == null)
                obj = new kalender();
        }
     }
}
```

Model

```
 public class kalender
 {
     //public string Datum { get; set; }
     //  [Required]  
     //  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
     //  public Nullable<System.DateTime> Datum { get; set; }

     public string Datum { get; set; }    
     [Required]    
     public string Password { get; set; }
     [Required]  
     public string Type { get; set; }
     [Required]
     [Key]
     public int SelectedEnumId { get; set; }
     [Required]  
     public TestEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model PE1.Models.kalender
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
}


@{
    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions();
    options.HttpMethod = "POST";
    options.Confirm = "Zeker?";
    options.OnBegin = "OnBegin";
    options.OnComplete = "OnComplete";
    options.OnFailure = "OnFailure";
    options.OnSuccess = "OnSuccess";
    options.LoadingElementId = "divProgress";
    options.LoadingElementDuration = 1000;
    options.UpdateTargetId = "divResponse";
    options.InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter;

}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { // will trigger when the document is ready
        $('.datepicker').datepicker(); //Initialise any date pickers

    });
</script>
    <div>
       <h1>Online Kalender</h1> 
        <div id="kader">
      <p>THuis</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", options))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Kaldender</legend>
        @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Password, listItems)*@<br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)<br />

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)<br />
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.MyEnum)

        <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Datum)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Datum, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here..." })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Datum)
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
    </fieldset>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Klik hier om een Ajax ActionLink uit te voeren", "ProcessLink", options)
}
```

enum

```
public enum TestEnum : int
{
    taak,
    vergadering
}
```

my output is wrong how can i change it ?

{
  "Datum": "10/28/2014",
  "Password": "hrth",
  "Type": null,
  "SelectedEnumId": 0,
  "MyEnum": 0,
  "rand1": 0
}{
  "Datum": "10/28/2014",
  "Password": "hrth",
  "Type": null,
  "SelectedEnumId": 0,
  "MyEnum": 0,
  "rand1": 0
}

this is my json file but i need this
[
{
  "Datum": "10/28/2014",
  "Password": "hrth",
  "Type": null,
  "SelectedEnumId": 0,
  "MyEnum": 0,
  "rand1": 0
},{
  "Datum": "10/28/2014",
  "Password": "hrth",
  "Type": null,
  "SelectedEnumId": 0,
  "MyEnum": 0,
  "rand1": 0
}
]

Comment: ye thanks its works, But now i got errors 
  "Datum": "10/01/2014",
  "Password": "zfz",
  "Type": null,
  "SelectedEnumId": 1,
  "MyEnum": 0
}{
  "Datum": "10/01/2014",
  "Password": "zfz",
  "Type": null,
  "SelectedEnumId": 1,
  "MyEnum": 0
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Overload for the SteamWriter object that appends to a file instead of overwriting a file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(JsonFileName1, true))
{
    writer.Write(json);

}
```

Notice the addition of the `bool` true in the StreamWriter constructor

Comment: thanks but my output file is wrong How can i late it work with this tags [] now i cant read it in with derialize and datatalbes because the file format is not good

Comment: I couldn't tell you that. I suggest you research some into JSON and more over, general coding. All my answer does it suggest to just append to your file instead of overwriting it